# Ubuntu 14.04 Sound Not Working

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

<strike>Okay so I plugged in a headphone, and then the sound stopped working. I took the headphone out and the sound still wasn't working. Restarted, still didn't work. So I looked up on how to fix the sound and stuff, and I think I just screwed up my computer even more. This is my sound settings:
[image]</strike>

none of my output devices from before are showing!
[image]

this is what my pulseaudio volume control is.

Also the sound button isn't in the top of my computer anymore
[image]

Can someone help me please? I have been struggling on this for a long time and it is driving me crazy!

EDIT: I got this to come in my sound:
[image]

But clicking test sound doesn't do anything and the sound stil doesn't work.

Comment: The first of your added pictures looks like sound is near-muted (or set to no, or almost no volume).  Have you tried sliding the slider up so it's louder?

Comment: It doesn't let me slide up

Comment: If you go to Configuration (in `pavucontrol` is it currently set to dummy-output?) but next I'd try turning it off there, then back on.

Comment: @guiverc It is set to Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (unplugged)

Comment: My suggestion was to turn off at the last tab, then a few seconds later turn it back on (I'd also try whatever options you have available to you there).  If it's an issue with other settings on your screens I can't help sorry (i've no experience with sound thru hdmi or changing away from defaults)

Comment: @guiverc ugh okay, thanks for helping anyways :)

Comment: @guiverc Hey I've made some progress on this do you think you can help me based on the new solution?

Answer (score 0):

The first screenshot shows no sound card. It looks like you connect to an external monitor, could be the headphone and you did not exit the device properly. Redo what you did and make sure you select the PC sound card (Output Device) before exiting the external device.

Could be a dead sound card also or corrupt driver.

What do you read there:

```
inxi --extra -A
```

See the given solution there by Mr.reaysawa

[Headphones not detected if plugged in before boot Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118991/headphones-not-detected-if-plugged-in-before-boot-ubuntu-18-04/1120231#1120231)

Comment: Please look at my edited thing

Comment: Screenshot tells me that output is from an external device. Did you try the given link to reset the sound card? About inxi cmd line, do you see the graphic card: driver and manufacturer?

Comment: sheshank@sheshank-Inspiron:~$ inxi --extra -A
/usr/bin/inxi: illegal option -- -
Error 7: One of the options you entered in your script parameters: --extra
is not supported.The option may require extra arguments to work.
For supported options (and their arguments), check the help menu: inxi -h

Comment: Audio:     Card: Intel Device 9d70 driver: snd_hda_intel Sound: ALSA ver: k4.4.0-142-generic
if i do `inxi -A`

Comment: sheshank@sheshank-Inspiron:~$ rm -r ~/.config/pulse
sheshank@sheshank-Inspiron:~$ pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/home/sheshank/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/home/sheshank/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/home/sheshank/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authorization key '/home/sheshank/.pulse-cookie': No such file or director

Answer (score 0):

You can list the sound cards in the command line:

```
~$ pacmd list-cards
```

This should list the audio cards are installed on your pc and detected.

If you give the following message:

```
>>> 0 card(s) available.
```

Please try using the following command to detect which audio cards your PC has installed, but not detected.

```
~$ lspci | grep -i audio
```

Please tell us the results you obtained to continue to help you.

Comment: http://freetexthost.com/scte0evbqp this is the output

Comment: I see that it has and detects the audio card. Please try **alsamixer** on the command line and verify that the audio card is selected and that the levels of headphones, speakers, PCM are activated. `$  alsamixer`

Comment: Verify that the correct audio card is selected once you have entered the alsamixer command, press F6 (according to the menu indicated) and select the audio card that may appear, for example: 1 HDA Intel PCH

Comment: okay i did that but it still doesn't work