# No sound on Kubuntu 18.10

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

Im a really noob with linux...recently i install the Kubuntu ARM OS (18.10) in a Samsung Chromebook 3 (INTEL N3060) and everything is fantastic...the OS is a really beauty BUT...i have no sound on it. 
In the sound panel,shows me Dummy Output...and build in audio,Profile: Off.
I dont know what to do really... since a couple of day im looking for a solution and y can do nothing to fix it. I really need help... Thanks in advanced.

PD: In gallium OS everything works fine...but Gallium OS i dont like it at all.

(My native language is not english i hope that someone understands me and help)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  The fact that you have something that works is your clue;  if it can be booted in 'live' mode I'd compare what Gallium OS (which I don't know) does & make Kubuntu do the same. `sudo lshw -C sound` means list-hardware class=sound to list recognized sound device, look for driver=  .. also compare [kernel] modules `lsmod` (list modules [drivers]) to see what's different between Gallium & Kubuntu.  This is suggestion only.

Answer (score 0):

Chromebooks are a happy/unhappy merge between a tablet and a laptop, in that they are more capable/use conventional architectures like x86, but also use proprietary drivers in most cases. GalliumOS is one of the more successful attempts to create a distribution for ChromeOS devices that uses compatible drivers with specific lines of devices, but this solution only works for devices that are explicitly developed for. In short, you might not be able to get sound working without extensive modification.

Finding an OS for a Chrome device is much more like finding a ROM for an Android phone than it is simply installing a new OS on your laptop and downloading drivers, since those drivers aren't necessarily available to download in the first place.

Comment: thanks for the Answer guys but...i have another trouble right now. I messed up my grub 2.02"thing"... I dont know what i did and i do not know how to fix it. 

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix there (@reaysawa). You may also try an higher kernel that contains patches for your system.

[Headphones not detected if plugged in before boot Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118991/headphones-not-detected-if-plugged-in-before-boot-ubuntu-18-04/1120231#1120231)

https://www.kernel.org/

Kernel PPA

https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D

Stay tuned and look for improvements for you system:

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=home