# Cannot switch audio output when external monitor is connected via HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi, external-monitor

When I connect an external monitor via HDMI I cannot switch audio output to built-in or headphones. I change output in Sound settings but audio still goes through the HDMI output.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - if I switch to `Digital Stereo 5.1 (HDMI) Output` in `Settings->Sound->Output -> Configuration` then `Settings->Sound->Output->Output Device` can be used to switch Output Device to Built-in or headphones.

On the other hand, if `Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output` is selected in `Settings->Sound->Output->Configuration` then switching Output Device in `Settings->Sound->Output->Output Device` does not do anything.

Answer (score 7):

I have, since posting the below, come across this answer referring to a similar problem in 18.04:  [Headphones not detected if plugged in before boot Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118991/headphones-not-detected-if-plugged-in-before-boot-ubuntu-18-04)

The suggested fix: "Solution: Remove any configuration files auto-generated at ~/.config/pulse" works in my case, and persists across logouts, suspensions, and reboots.

> I have a similar problem since upgrading to 20.04 and Gnome from 18.04 and Gnome >(where my HDMI connected monitor speakers and my laptop speakers/headphones >would switch via Settings>Sound>Output Device.)
> Now I have had to install Pulse Audio Volume Control to use headphones:
>
> 1. On the Configuration tab I can set anything but Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output >or Off, and the headphones will work and all normal volume controls work. (And I >can watch video on the external monitor.)
> 2. On the Output Devices tab Built-in Analog Stereo is active, Built-in Audio >Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) is inactive.
>
> If I use the Sound control in Settings>Sound>Output Device to change to >HDMI/Display Port - Built-in Audio:
>
> 1. The settings in PAVU immediately change to (Configuration) Digital Stereo(HDMI) Output and (Output Devices) both Speakers and HDMI show as active, but I only get sound from HDMI.
> 2. Switching the Output Device to Speakers or Headphone via Settings>Sound>Output Device makes no change to PAVU, and the sound continues to come from the HDMI connected monitor, where both Speakers and HDMI show as active.
>
> From this behaviour, I imagine that in 18.04 the switch in Settings>Sound>Output >Device was changing the Configuration in PAVU to Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output, >and that in 20.04 that is not happening. For now, I will simply ignore >Settings>Sound and head straight for PAVU.

Comment: After upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04 I could not switch audio output. It always stayed at the internal speakers of the laptop. Deleting all files in ~/.config/pulse and rebooting did the trick!

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 here, deleting /.config/pulse and rebooting also worked for me!